# How can I setup a Wireless Access point or and Ad-hoc network?

Tags: wireless, archlinux, dhcp, wireless-adapter

I would like to connect to my PI through wireless USB dongle, how can I setup an AP or an Ad-Hoc under Arch Linux?

Comment: Try following the instructions on the [Arch Linux Wireless Network guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup).

Comment: This article tells how to setup an Ad-Hoc network: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ad-hoc_networking

Comment: **Answerers:** Please don't just provide a link to a Wiki or a similar website; always provide a summary on [RaspberryPi.SE] to help combat link rot. Thank you for your cooperation!

Comment: @iUngi I cant see why you deleted this post, so I have reopened it. If you have found the answer on your own, please answer the question yourself.

Comment: For those using the Edimax Nano, this article has instructions for creating an AP: http://www.daveconroy.com/turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-hotspot-with-edimax-nano-usb-ew-7811un-rtl8188cus-chipset/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this question asks for instructions on Arch Linux, but since I have been struggling for several days with the exact same issue on Raspbian Wheezy I thought it might be helpful if I shared my solution anyway.

Basically, I ended up creating a solution where my Raspberry Pi (RPi) tries to connect to one of its known wireless networks, and if that do not succeed (WiFi is not in range or the DHCP is not leasing), the RPi creates an encrypted DHCP-enabled ad-hoc network instead. In that way, I can always access the RPi through SSH no matter where the RPi is located.

I use `wpa_supplicant` for managing the wireless WPA2 connections, and `iwconfig` for creating the encrypted ad-hoc network (with `dhcpd` for managing IP leases on the ad-hoc network).

I have compiled a complete tutorial on this subject which can be found here: http://lcdev.dk/2012/11/18/raspberry-pi-tutorial-connect-to-wifi-or-create-an-encrypted-dhcp-enabled-ad-hoc-network-as-fallback/

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Hello Lasse, it's better to copy this tutorial to this answer, instead of just linking to it. Of course, you may keep the credit for it by keeping the link at the top or bottom of your answer.

Comment: @Exeleration-G Hi, thanks for your advice - I thought of doing that, but the tutorial is quite long, so I came to the conclusion that it would be best to simply refer it. However, if I can get you to take a look at the length of the post and asses if I still should include it here, please reply and I will include it in case :)

Comment: Hmm, yes. I'm sorry, I just took a glance over your tutorial and didn't see how long it really was. It's indeed really long :D. Maybe better to keep it this way :-)

Comment: @Exeleration-G Okay, thanks ;) I will keep it this way for now then :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (in my opinion) is to use the create_ap script as linked in: 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_Access_Point

Answer (score 0):

For setting up a Pi as a wifi access point try my site at www.pi-point.co.uk, which as long as your wifi adaptor supports AP mode should hopefully get you sorted.

I know this isn't for ARCH but hopefully it will give you all the clues you need.